# Getting response from nested Async funtion in React

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have 3 function to login a user on my React web application.

1. Function C: Calling Login function from Login HTML Page

---

```
 const handleLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //  Calling FUNCTION B
        loginUser({ email, password }).then((value) => console.log('in promise then : ' + value));
    
        console.log('in login page: ' + response);
    };
```

2. Function B: Making authorization

---

```
export async function loginUser(loginPayload) {

     //  Calling FUNCTION C
     AuthDataService.login(loginPayload)
      .then((response) => {
          var modifiedResponse = response;
          console.log('in AuthDataService: ' + JSON.stringify(modifiedResponse));
          return modifiedResponse;
      });
}
```

3. Function A: Calling Server

---

```
class AuthDataService {
  async login(data) {
    return await http.post('/login', data).then((response) => {
        return response;
    });
  }
}
```

Problem is that, in Function B response is logged correctly but in Function A response(value) is undefined. Shouldn't function C wait until Function B is finished?
What should I change?

Comment: You're not returning anything from `loginUser`.

Comment: @Ivar There is written return data after console.log, isn't is enough?

Comment: That returns a value to the `(response) => { ... }` callback arrow function. Not the `loginUser` function.

Comment: There is no variable `response` declared anywhere in function A?

Comment: Which library are you using for your api requests with `http`? if i know i can test somethings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `loginUser` function.

**NOTE:** No need for async if are using `.then`

Refactoring you can do like below

```
export function loginUser(loginPayload) {
  //  Calling FUNCTION C
  return AuthDataService.login(loginPayload).then((response) => {
    var modifiedResponse = response;
    return data; // not sure from where it's coming
  });
}
```

class: no need to then if you are not doing anything with response.

```
login(data) {
    return http.post('/login', data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: in `handleLogin` you're not assinging anything to the response value.
Second: in loginUser and login you're not returning any value.

you can try this:

```js
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const response = await  loginUser({ email, password }).then((value) => console.log('in promise then : ' + value));

  console.log('in login page: ' + response);
};

export const loginUser = async (loginPayload) => {
  return AuthDataService.login(loginPayload).then((response) => JSON.stringify(response));
}

class AuthDataService {
  async login(data) {
    return await http.post('/login', data)
  }
}
```